# How can I use Confidence Interval to show that two distributions' difference is not significantly large (2 distributions are comparable)

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

thanks for helping me in advance.

I have built a new algorithm to generate a high resolution picture, measured by PSNR, the higher the better. And I have a baseline model as well. I run both models over 5000 images, to get 2 distributions regarding the PSNR for each image generated by each model:`myDistribution: [x_1, x_2, x_3....], baselineDistribution: [z_1,z_2,z_3,....]`.

My goal is first to prove that my method could output a similar performance compared to the baseline model. ***Meaning that the difference between these 2 methods' output should be 0***. Thus, I calculated another distribution of the difference by subtracting the 2 distributions I have obtained, denoted as `[myDistribution - baselineDistribution] -> diff: [d_1, d_2,d_3,...]`

Now, if I calculate the 95% confidence interval using the diff distribution [d_1, d_2, d_3....] by doing `d_mean +- 2*std_d`, it gives me an interval of **[-0.18,0.23]**. Can I infer that since this interval is tight, and 0 is within this interval, I can be 95% sure that my model could be comparable to the baseline?

Thanks!